# Reindex Task Failing Randomly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, index

We use the built-in maintenance plan to reindex (and backup, etc.) our production SQL Server.  The problem we are currently having is the reindex task started failing randomly this week after months of smooth operation.  It has failed three out of the last six nights (it runs nightly), and it always fails on the ASPNETDB database.  This database is Microsoft's ASP.Net user/role database (which I hate BTW, but that's another story).

If I remove the failing database from the list of reindexes database, the task succeeds.  If I remove all other databases *except* the failing database, the task still succeeds.  If I follow the above two steps, then immediately run the task as normal, it succeeds.  I see no rhyme or reason to this.

When the task fails, the log message looks like what I have pasted below (no errors that I can see).  The message always ends with the last statement being "ALTER INDEX [PK__aspnet_P__32...".

Any thoughts what might be going on here?

> Message Executed as user: mydbname\i2SQLclstsvc. ...0.2500.0 for
>   64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.
>   Started:  8:46:39 PM  Progress: 2012-03-15 20:46:40.33     Source:
>   {3D0CB67E-0B04-419A-BA8F-CDD8F0519612}      Executing query "DECLARE
>   @Guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER      EXECUTE msdb..sp...".: 100% complete  End
>   Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15 20:46:54.74     Source: Rebuild Index
>   Task      Executing query "USE [ASPNETDB]  ".: 2% complete  End
>   Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15 20:46:54.76     Source: Rebuild Index
>   Task      Executing query "ALTER INDEX [aspnet_Applications_Index] ON
>   [dbo].[...".: 4% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15
>   20:46:54.76     Source: Rebuild Index Task      Executing query "USE
>   [ASPNETDB]  ".: 6% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15
>   20:46:54.76     Source: Rebuild Index Task      Executing query "ALTER
>   INDEX [PK__aspnet_A_*C93A4C98014935CB] ON [d...".: 9% complete  End
>   Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15 20:46:54.76     Source: Rebuild Index
>   Task      Executing query "USE [ASPNETDB]  ".: 11% complete  End
>   Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15 20:46:54.76     Source: Rebuild Index
>   Task      Executing query "ALTER INDEX
>   [UQ*_aspnet_A_*17477DE40425A276] ON [d...".: 13% complete  End
>   Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15 20:46:54.76     Source: Rebuild Index
>   Task      Executing query "USE [ASPNETDB]  ".: 15% complete  End
>   Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15 20:46:54.77     Source: Rebuild Index
>   Task      Executing query "ALTER INDEX
>   [UQ*_aspnet_A__3091033107020F21] ON [d...".: 18% complete  End
>   Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15 20:46:54.77     Source: Rebuild Index
>   Task      Executing query "USE [ASPNETDB]  ".: 20% complete  End
>   Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15 20:46:54.83     Source: Rebuild Index
>   Task      Executing query "ALTER INDEX [aspnet_Membership_index] ON
>   [dbo].[as...".: 22% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15
>   20:46:54.83     Source: Rebuild Index Task      Executing query "USE
>   [ASPNETDB]  ".: 25% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15
>   20:46:54.87     Source: Rebuild Index Task      Executing query "ALTER
>   INDEX [PK__aspnet_M__1788CC4D1FCDBCEB] ON [d...".: 27% complete  End
>   Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15 20:46:54.87     Source: Rebuild Index
>   Task      Executing query "USE [ASPNETDB]  ".: 29% complete  End
>   Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15 20:46:54.87     Source: Rebuild Index
>   Task      Executing query "ALTER INDEX [aspnet_Paths_index] ON
>   [dbo].[aspnet_...".: 31% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15
>   20:46:54.87     Source: Rebuild Index Task      Executing query "USE
>   [ASPNETDB]  ".: 34% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15
>   20:46:54.87     Source: Rebuild Index Task      Executing query "ALTER
>   INDEX [PK__aspnet_P_*CD67DC5859063A47] ON [d...".: 36% complete  End
>   Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15 20:46:54.87     Source: Rebuild Index
>   Task      Executing query "USE [ASPNETDB]  ".: 38% complete  End
>   Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15 20:46:54.87     Source: Rebuild Index
>   Task      Executing query "ALTER INDEX
>   [PK*_aspnet_P__CD67DC5960A75C0F] ON [d...".: 40% complete  End
>   Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15 20:46:54.87     Source: Rebuild Index
>   Task      Executing query "USE [ASPNETDB]  ".: 43% complete  End
>   Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15 20:46:54.87     Source: Rebuild Index
>   Task      Executing query "ALTER INDEX
>   [aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser_index1]...".: 45% complete  End
>   Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15 20:46:54.87     Source: Rebuild Index
>   Task      Executing query "USE [ASPNETDB]  ".: 47% complete  End
>   Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15 20:46:54.87     Source: Rebuild Index
>   Task      Executing query "ALTER INDEX
>   [aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser_ncindex...".: 50% complete  End
>   Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15 20:46:54.87     Source: Rebuild Index
>   Task      Executing query "USE [ASPNETDB]  ".: 52% complete  End
>   Progress  Progress: 2012-03-15 20:46:54.87     Source: Rebuild Index
>   Task      Executing query "ALTER INDEX [PK__aspnet_P__32...  The
>   package execution fa...  The step failed.

Comment: What could be happening is that you are droping the index `PK__aspnet_P__3214EC06778AC167` in your maintenance plan.  I believe the list of indexes to get rebuilt is created prior to the start, so if that table or index (the table is actually `aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser`) is getting dropped, executing the `ALTER INDEX PK__aspnet_P__3214EC06778AC167 on aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser rebuild ...` will fail.  Check to see what is happening with that index/table through the generated plan.  I bet you'll find something odd like that.

Comment: Have you looked to see if there is anything else that's running around the time the maintenance plan fails?

Comment: Are you seeing deadlocks while index maintenance runs? (I've seen this happen before.) Is the rebuild task set to rebuild online, and are you running an edition of SQL Server that supports online rebuilds? Have you considered doing an index reorganization on this database instead of a full rebuild (this is always an online operation)?

Comment: Try to manually re-index that database and see if that come up with the same error.

Comment: run a checkDB on each database manually.
DBCC CHECKDB (<Database Name>) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS

Answer (score 1):

A known reason for reindex failure is a full log.
Depending on your recovery model, the frequency at which you backup your log and the activity on your database, you might have "random" crashes.
If you monitor the size of your log or have access to you server ERRORLOG you should be able to validate this hypothesis and take appropriate measures if it's validated.